# Error using a RecyclerView in Fragment - App was Stopped

Tags: java, android

I am new here. But always resort to StackOverFlow to resolve my doubts. Almost always I can do that. But I cant find a solution to a problem that I'm having with use RecyclerView, filling it with Fragment. I do not have much experience in programming for Android. Thank you very much in advance.

LogCat:

```
`01-12 17:45:53.711    8622 8622/br.com.easyin.login_singup_databasefromphone E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: br.com.easyin.login_singup_databasefromphone, PID: 8622
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.easyin.login_singup_databasefromphone/br.com.easyin.login_singup_databasefromphone.Events}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at br.com.easyin.login_singup_databasefromphone.EventFragment.onCreateView(EventFragment.java:32)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1965)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1078)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1259)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1624)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1234)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6258)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
```

Events.Java

```
package br.com.easyin.login_singup_databasefromphone;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Events extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    //FRAGMENT

    EventFragment frag = (EventFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mainFrag");
    if(frag == null){
        frag = new EventFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.EventsLayout, frag, "mainFrag");
        ft.commit();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_events, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public List<Event> getSetEventList(int qtd){
    String[] attractions = new String[]{"Jorge & Mateus", "Raimundos", "Los Hermanos", "CPM 22", "Capital Inicial", "Cássia Eller", "Engenheiros do Hawaii", "HERVA DOCE", "Jota Quest", "Legião Urbana", "Mamonas Assassinas", "Charlie Brown Jr", "Pedra Leticia"};
    String[] nameEvents = new String[]{"Girus Show", "Divina Folia", "Pitapirou", "Rock in Rio", "Loucamente Apaixonados", "Evento Cultural Mineiro"};
    String[] dates = new String[]{"27/01/2016", "10/02/2016", "05/01/2016", "11/02/2016", "30/05/2016", "24/06/2016", "11/09/2016", "27/09/2016", "11/06/2016"};
    String[] price = new String[]{"R$ 50,00", "R$ 75,00", "R$ 54,00", "R$ 125,00", "R$ 25,00", "R$ 250,00"};

    List<Event> listAux = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i <qtd; i++){
        Event e = new Event(nameEvents[i % nameEvents.length], attractions[i % attractions.length], dates[i % dates.length], price[i % price.length]);
        listAux.add(e);
    }
    return listAux;
}
```

}

Activity_Events.xml(I want the list to appear in this layout)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="br.com.easyin.login_singup_databasefromphone.Events"
android:orientation="vertical">

<SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/svEvents"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/EventsLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EventFragment.java

```
package br.com.easyin.login_singup_databasefromphone;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EventFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {


private RecyclerView rvEvents;
private List<Event> eventList;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event, container, false);



    rvEvents = (RecyclerView)rvEvents.findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
    rvEvents.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rvEvents.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            LinearLayoutManager llm = (LinearLayoutManager) rvEvents.getLayoutManager();
            EventAdapter adapter = (EventAdapter) rvEvents.getAdapter();

            if (eventList.size() == llm.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() + 1) {
                List<Event> listAux = ((Events) getActivity()).getSetEventList(10);

                for (int i = 0; i < listAux.size(); i++) {
                    adapter.addListItem(listAux.get(i), eventList.size());
                }
            }

        }
    });

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rvEvents.setLayoutManager(llm);

    eventList = ((Events)getActivity()).getSetEventList(10);
    EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(getActivity(), eventList);
    rvEvents.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}

}
```

fragment_event.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="br.com.easyin.login_singup_databasefromphone.EventFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_list"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

item_event.java

```
package br.com.easyin.login_singup_databasefromphone;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class item_Event extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item__event);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item__event, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

acitivity_item_event.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Event Name"
    android:id="@+id/tvEventName"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Producer: "
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvEventName"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="sadasd"
    android:id="@+id/tvNameGer"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView16" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Attractions: "
    android:id="@+id/textView18"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="safadads"
    android:id="@+id/tvAttractions"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView18" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Date: "
    android:id="@+id/textView19"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="dfsfsdafsdfsd"
    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView19"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView19" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Price: "
    android:id="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="dasdasdsad"
    android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvDate" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/vw_divider"
    android:layout_height="0.8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#0162c3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Change `rvEvents = (RecyclerView)rvEvents.findViewById(R.id.rv_list);` to `rvEvents = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.rv_list);`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DamianKozlak . Really was wrong. But the error continues. When I start activity_events.xml in the app appears => ("Application Name" stopped).